# video not playing embedded vimeo video jquery fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h2>fancyBox v3.2 - Iframe</h2>

<a data-fancybox href="https://vimeo.com/191947042">
  Vimeo video
</a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain why my video isn't playing after popup it's need to be done by evening had a look at all sources possible i am not getting a way out of it ?

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0xnLd2yj/. Check the console for errors and the paths to you local copy of fancybox

Comment: the popup is opening and i too had a look in jsfiddle its working over there but not playing a video in neither mozilla nor chrome when i open the file

Comment: Are you testing on your local machine? ie. a `file://` based URL? If so you're probably being blocked from loading the video by browser security. Run on a webserver

Comment: yes and thanks now i served it from localhost and running fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8nTZ/
Check it out and replicate.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://vimeo.com/123456">open vimeo</a>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure you are linking your js files correctly!

Comment: the popup is opening and i too had a look in jsfiddle its working over there but not playing a video in neither mozilla nor chrome when i open the file

Comment: Ok, check your links to the libraries (jquery and fancybox). You can try to use a links from CDN, just to make sure that they are correctly included.

Comment: i just need to run it from localhost/server